# Rename multiple directories using rename command, name involves parenthresis

Tags: bash, rename

I've got a list of directories marked with "(Done)" at the end of the label.

For example: "Folder 1 (Done)"

I'm looking to remove "(Done)" from each directory using the rename command. Because it's a special character I'm using the escape character.

```
rename s/\(Done\)//g *
```

However, this command doesn't work. It removes the word "Done" and leaves the parentheses: "Folder 1 ()"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\` is a quoting operator in the shell syntax so:

```
rename s/\(Done\)//g *
```

Is the same as running:

```
rename 's/(Done)//g' *
```

And `(`, `)` are special characters in the perl regular expression syntax (which `rename` uses) and need to be prefixed with `\` (or changed to `[(]` and `[)]`) so they are treated literally.

So here, you want:

```
rename 's/\s*\(Done\)//g' ./*
```

Here also adding `\s*` to remove any whitespace before `(Done)`, and a `./` prefix as some variants of `rename` would choke on file names that start with `-`.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your working solution. Struggling to get my head around the first explanation of how rename s/\(Done\)//g *    =   rename 's/(Done)//g' *

Comment: I've just quickly googled "Shell syntax backlash" and I can only find it's use as an escape character, not as a quoting operator. In this example the backlash is inbetween the first / and (Done\) - yet the whole statement is surrounded by the single quote

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
rename 's/\(.*\)|\[.*\]//g' *
```

Otherwise without using `rename` command (OT):

```
for file in folder*; do                                                          
    mv "$file" "${file/\(Done\)/}"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `find`:

```
find topdir -maxdepth 1 -type d -name '* (Done)' -exec sh -c '
    for pathname do
        mv "$pathname" "${pathname%" (Done)"}"
    done' sh {} +
```

This uses `find` to pick out the directories that have `␣(Done)` at the end of their names and then uses a standard parameter substitution to remove that string.

No check is made to make sure there isn't already a directory/file with the target name in the same directory.

---

The `sh -c` script above could obviously be run by itself too, with minor modifications to do the tests that `find` did for it:

```
for pathname in topdir/*' (Done)'/; do
    mv "$pathname" "${pathname%' (Done)/'}"
done
```